# Caching Json / Rest network responses

Tags: android, caching

For my Android app, I want to keep the network traffic as low as possible (of course).
I'm aware of [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) but it only works on API >= 13 so it's not an option for me.

I thought of of using using the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html), use the `REST` Url as the key (given theres no `POST` data). 
When I get a response from the server (`JSON`) I instantly create POJOs from it with `Gson`.

- What's better to use as the value? The `JSON` String, then deserialize it again with `Gson` or to store the `POJO`s? I know deserializing takes a little cpu time, but perhaps there's a downside to storing the `POJO`s in my cache?
- Say I have an Activity that diplays the content of a `POJO` called 'Product' (that I got from the server as `JSON`). On orientation change, can I just forget about keeping the Product `POJO` (via `savedInstanceState` or whatever) because the network call to retrieve it again will most probably be 'free' anyway (because it's still in the cache)?
- Would it be better to have separate caches for different types of Objects or just use one big cache?
- Any advise on how to determine a good size for the cache (in `MiB` or just number of Entries)

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is Virgil Dobjanschi's Google I/O 2010 talk on RESTful patterns for Android: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

In a nutshell, he advocates for using SQLite to keep track of the state of your HTTP requests and caching data to minimize requests.  I found a sample implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429997/Sample-Implementation-of-Virgil-Dobjanschis-Rest-p), but you may want to search around for more resources on the patterns outlined in that talk.

Since originally answering this, several good open source libraries for Android that will handle caching HTTP requests have come into existence.  [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) are two of solid options.